# NG Style not changing background color

Tags: angular

I have an `ngStyle` directive that I am trying to use however it is not changing the `background-color` of the toggle checkbox I have. When the toggle is false I want to have a grey background and when it is true I want to have an orange background.

```
<div class="relative">
 <input id="toggleBroker" type="checkbox" class="hidden" formControlName='sendToBroker' name="sendToBroker" [(ngModel)]="brokerDetails.sendtoBroker" (onChange)="!sendToBroker = sendToBroker"/>
 <div id="toggleBrokerBG" class="toggle__line w-10 h-4 rounded-full shadow-inner" [ngStyle]="'!sendToBroker' ? {'background-color': 'grey'} : {'background-color': 'orange'}" ></div>
 <div class="toggle__dot absolute w-6 h-6 bg-white rounded-full shadow inset-y-0 left-0"></div>
</div>
```

[image: Image of toggle checkbox]

Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it should be:

```html
<div class="relative">
 <input id="toggleBroker" type="checkbox" class="hidden" formControlName='sendToBroker' name="sendToBroker" [(ngModel)]="brokerDetails.sendtoBroker" (onChange)="!sendToBroker = sendToBroker"/>
 <div id="toggleBrokerBG" class="toggle__line w-10 h-4 rounded-full shadow-inner" [ngStyle]="{ 'background-color': !sendToBroker ? 'grey' : 'orange' }" ></div>
 <div class="toggle__dot absolute w-6 h-6 bg-white rounded-full shadow inset-y-0 left-0"></div>
</div>
```

Your tertiary expression comes after the property, only for the value assignment. See [the official docs](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle) for details.

Comment: This is setting the grey but when I switch to true it does not set the orange

Comment: That's a different issue and question regarding change detection. I did note that you are using both a property for reactive forms (`formControlName`) and a binding for `[(ngModel)]`. You should consider using just reactive forms. Then you could check for `formGroup.value.sendToBroker` (replacing `formGroup` with whatever name your group variable actually has).